# VS C# sql unable to connect to any sql host

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I am knocking together a short program mainly to try and learn some basics. I am finding an issue with this part of code:

```
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=serverT;User Id=user;password=password;database=healer");
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = new MySqlCommand("SELECT version FROM version", connection).ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
etc etc etc
}
```

Now when i build and run this, It works perfectly, no problems whatsoever, it connects up and i can read without any issue.. (The server is hosted online btw)

When i give out the exe/mysql.data.dll to anyone to run, they are thrown the exception of being unable to connect to any sql host.

I just cant see why I can connect, and they can't. I have tried this now on 3 other remote machines and they all fail to connect, but Mine works OK.

There are no access rules on the hosted sql database, I am allowing access from all IPs

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: What exception do they get?

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear above
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x800004005) Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts.
and i keep hitting enter and submitting this early!

Answer (score 1):

You are hard coding the connection string into your code. Your clients have a different server  therefore they need a different connection string.

You need to create a form or a config file where the connection parameters are retrieved from.

Please read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

Comment: If they are accessing my pre-set sql server to look  up the details, wont the string be the same ? or is it generated on the local machine somehow, i have set the url in the variable passed to the mysqlconnection thinking would be easiest way

Comment: I have just rechecked the permissions on the database and there are no restrictions for the user im connection to as in from their location, I have tested the db from this location and can connect. just seems my app doesn't want to. The string is hardcoded as i origionally had it in an encrypted config file, but moved to coded plain text for testing